# Confused about って in this sentence

Tags: translation, particles, particle-って

A man and a woman who had undergone hardship together as children before being forced to part meet again and remember their last words to each other.

The woman says:

> 生きてて良かったって、心の底から思える瞬間って、どんな感じかしら？

I think the first part of the sentence

> 生きてて良かったって

means

> “It’s good to keep on living”

the って here being a quotative particle since
 生きてて良かった was the last thing the man said to the woman. (Please correct me if I’m mistaken).

The second part

> 心の底から思える瞬間って

confuses me.  What is the function of the って here?  It doesn’t seem like a quotative particle.  I guess it translates to something like:

> a moment that seemed to come from the bottom of your heart.

And I think the last part

> どんな感じかしら？

translates as:

> Was that your feeling, I wonder?

So, I think the meaning of the sentence (idiomatically) is something like:

> You said, “It’s good to keep on living”, like you really believed it.  Was that what you were feeling, I wonder?

Is this correct and what is the function of って in the second part of the sentence?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> 生きてて良かった**って**、心の底から思える瞬間**って**、どんな感じかしら？

These two って's are not the same.

The first って is a quotative particle. From [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/147762/meaning/m0u/):

> って
>   ［格助］
>   １ 引用する語、または文の下に付いて、次に来る動作・作用の内容を表す。…と。「金を貸してくれ**って**頼まれた」「読書しろ**って**言われた」

The って is a quotative particle and means と. The two example sentences given in the dictionary can be rephrased as 「金を貸してくれ**と**頼まれた」「読書しろ**と**言われた」.  って is more colloquial than と.

And the second is a binding particle (係助詞). From the same dictionary:

> って
>   ［係助］
>   １ ある事柄を話題として取り上げて示す意を表す。…は。…というのは。「あなた**って**親切な人ね」「彼**って**だれのこと」

The って is used to introduce something as a topic. Means ～は or ～というのは. The examples can be rephrased 「あなた**は**親切な人ね」「彼**というのは**だれのこと」.  って is more colloquial than は or というのは.

So your sentence can be rewritten as:

> 『生きてて良かった*』**と**、心の底から思える瞬間**というのは**、どんな感じかしら？

*lit.* Speaking of the moment when you can feel "I'm lucky to be alive" from the bottom of your heart, how would it feel? / what would it be like?
⇒ I wonder what the moment would be like when you can feel from the bottom of your heart "I feel lucky to be alive. / Thank God I'm alive."

*The た in ～～よかった here is the modal た, explained here: [Usage of plain i-adjectives or た form (悪かったｖ悪い、良かったｖいい etc）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21377/9831)

---

Breakdown:

> 生きてて -- *lit.* I'm alive (and) → to be alive
>   良かった -- (I find it) good.
>   って、--  quotative
>   心の底から -- from the bottom of your heart
>   思える瞬間 -- the moment you can feel
>   って、-- topical
>   どんな感じかしら？ -- What would it be like?

Comment: is there anything ommit in the sentence like for instance 生きてて良かったっていう　or something like that?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Hmm no I don't think there's nothing left out there. 「Sentence」って+思う, 感じる, 言う etc. is a colloquial way of saying 「Sentence」と+思う, 感じる, 言う etc.

Comment: I think what is confusing me is that usually i see 思う right after って, but here we have 心の底から

Comment: You can parse it 「Sentence + って、（心の底から）思える瞬間」≂ 「Sentence + って、（本当に）思える瞬間」"the moment when you can really feel ~~".  心の底から is an adverbial phrase, modifying the 思える.

Comment: @Chocolate, with regard to 生きてて良かった, in meaning, is it “It’s good to be alive” or “it’s good to stay alive/keep being alive” as given in the first answer [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/whats-the-difference-between-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84-and-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84)?  I’m still not quite sure how to interpret the ～ている form here.

Comment: @Noob 生きてい(る) here means "to be alive (now at this moment)", or maybe "to have been alive (until now). (=今まで生きていて～)" And the た in
 よかった is the modal た, as explained here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21377/9831 So it's more like "Thank God I'm alive."

Comment: Thank you for your succinct explanations of both って and た.  It is all much clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

> 生きてて良かったって、心の底から思える瞬間って、どんな感じかしら？
>
> I think the first part of the sentence means “It’s good to keep on
>   living” the って here being a quotative particle since 生きてて良かった was the
>   last thing the man said to the woman. (Please correct me if I’m
>   mistaken). The second part 心の底から思える瞬間って confuses me. What is the
>   function of the って here?

Your understanding of って is correct. Both って here are used in the same way. It's just the sentence is basically saying
 生きてて良かったと思える瞬間　というのはどんな感じかしら？ The whole thing is something thought by the speaker. The 心の底から is an adverb to 思える.

> 〔［生きてて良かった］って、｛心の底から｝思える瞬間〕って、どんな感じかしら？

Comment: Could someone explain why this need to be downvoted? I feel downvoting is not something easily done without reason. The function says "This answer is not useful". Isn't this quite a strong objection?

Comment: I was not the downvoter but i have a question, why 思う is a pottential here?

Comment: Potential? Do you mean how 思う can be the verb taking 生きてて良かったって as the content/object?

Comment: I find I get down-voted when information is incorrect.  I didn't do the down-vote, but speaking from personal experience, that's probably it.

Comment: @karlalou yeah, the sentence has 思える instead of 思う, why is that?

Comment: @Felipe Oliveira All right. 思う is also grammatical, but this is the part we naturally use 思える instead. I find 思える can convey the implication that the speaker cannot think so right this moment; 今はそう思えない.