# Whats is the meaning of って in this?

Tags: particle-って

あんたそりゃ「押しかけ女房」ってやつだな
I undestand this like: "Youre that "Oshikake niyoubou" guy" (if I'm wrong  please tell me) but I cant understand the meaning of って

Can somebody help me? Im sorry for my bad english too.

Comment: The やつ doesn't mean "guy". そりゃ～～ってやつだ (≂それは～～というものだ) That's what's called ~~, That's what you'd call ~~.

Comment: Also, just in case you're wondering/unsure, apparently 押しかけ女房 refers to a woman who forced her husband into marriage. [Here's the Japanese Wikipedia page for the term.](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%8A%BC%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E5%A5%B3%E6%88%BF)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 「～って」 expresses 同格 (apposition). Means 「～という」. According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> って
>    〘格助詞〙
>   ❷ **同格**を表す。**・・・という**。「エゴン・シーレ**って**画家、知ってる？」「用**って**ほどのこともないんだが・・・」「気にしなくてもいい**って**ことよ」

The って in your example is the appositive case particle. The examples in the dictionary can be rewritten as 「エゴン・シーレ**という**画家は知ってますか？」「用**という**ほどのこともないんだが・・・」. 「って」 is more colloquial than 「という」. Your sentence can be rephrased as:

> あんたそりゃ「押しかけ女房」**って**やつだな。
>   ⇒ あんた、それは「押しかけ女房」**という**やつだな。/ **という**ものだな。

"Say, / Hey, that's what's called 押しかけ女房 / that's what you call 押しかけ女房."

The やつ here doesn't mean "guy", but "thing" or "what (is called...)", ≂「もの (in the
 sense of 物, not 者)」.

And the あんた is vocative (呼びかけ). It's not the subject of the sentence. The subject is それ in そりゃ (＝それ+は).

---

The って here is not the quotative particle (=格助詞「と」), nor the topical particle (=係助詞「は」「というのは」), which I explained in [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/50251/9831).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer it was very complete. I always have a lot of troubles with "casual" or "informal" japanese, I have a lot to learn. Is there some answer or post where somebody talk about "informal" japanese?

Comment: @Pixiebell We have a lot of questions and answers tagged with "colloquial language" -> https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colloquial-language?sort=votes&pageSize=50 and "contractions" -> https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contractions?sort=votes&pageSize=50 Would these be of some help?