# Ending a sentence in ～てないでこと

Tags: anime, particle-こと

This is from an anime (Kanon ep 1, 07:58). Yuichi says:

いや　お前って　変わってないよなあ

Which I understand to mean "you really haven't changed." I believe the first って is replacing は and 変わってない is short for 変わっていない.

Nayuki replies:

それで 成長してないで こと？

From the context this seems to mean "by that are you saying I haven't grown up?" I know that (verb 1)ないで(verb 2) means "do verb 2 without doing verb 1". But verb 2 seems to be elided here and I don't know what it is. I thought maybe こと is short for ことがある but that doesn't totally make sense. I would expect something more like this:

それで 成長したことがない？

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Edit: Chocolate notes that this is probably a transcribing error in the subtitles and she probably actually said:

それって 成長してないって こと？

I'm guessing the って here is an example of って as indirect speech. But still not clear on the role of こと in this context (I'm guessing some kind of nominalizer).

Comment: `それで 成長してないで こと？`  -- Should be 「それ**って**成長してない**って**こと？」

Comment: @Chocolate I'm going off what the subtitles say but it does really sound like she's saying それって and ないって. It's possible the transcriber made an error.

Comment: My guess is it was transcribed by a Chinese speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be 「それって成長してないってこと？」

You can parse it this way:

> それって、「成長してない」ってこと？

The first って is the topic marker (≈ 「は」「というのは」).
The second って is the quotative marker (≈ 「という」).

(For these two usages of って, here's a related thread: [Confused about って in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50246/9831) )

So the sentence can be rewritten as:

> それは、「成長していない」ということ（ですか？）

which would mean:

> Is it that I haven't grown up? /
> By that, do you mean I haven't grown up?

Comment: After you fixed the transcription I guessed that the first って was は and the second was quotative, but a little unclear on こと in this context. I'm thinking it's like, "成長していない」という" means "said I haven't grown up" and then こと nominalizes it as "the act of saying I haven't grown up" and then it is compared to それ which is "that act you just committed (of saying the first line)". Would it still make sense without こと or is the nominalizer essential?

Comment: The こと is a nominalizer. It is essential here. それ refers to what the other person just said. (それ=「お前は変わっていない」) So it's literally "Is it(="I haven't changed") that I haven't grown up?" 「それは、[文]ということだ」corresponds to "It is that [sentence]" >> "It means that [sentence]".