# Is "あれって" one word or two?

Tags: translation

The sentence

> あれって、血？

apparently translates to

> Is that blood?

I'm confused by "あれって": is this a single word, or "あれ" + "って"? What's a good literal translation of this sentence?

Comment: Just to make sure. Would you consider 「あれは」 in 「あれは、血？」 as one word, or two?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/50251/9831 -- It's the 2nd って.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's two words. This って is a colloquial topic particle used in place of は. See: [Difference between って and は as topic marker](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15004/5010)

> What's a good literal translation of this sentence?

"Is that blood?", or maybe "That is blood?". The sentence in question is structurally not different from "あれは血(ですか)?".

Comment: And just to be clear: "あれ" in this case is "彼", correct?

Comment: @George 彼 is かれ ("he"), which is not あれ ("that"). In what situation do you say "Is he blood?"

Comment: あれ *can* be written as 彼れ, but not 彼